# How to set up filter for isort as external tool in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, isort

I'm trying to set up isort as external tool in PyCharm. I'm unable to set up filter so that file paths are links.

Output from isort is:

```
ERROR: C:\dev\path\to\a\project\file.py Imports are incorrectly sorted.
```

According to [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/add-edit-filter-dialog-2.html) putting  `$FILE_PATH$` should be sufficient yet it does not work for me. I've tried several regex styles without any success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr use `$FILE_PATH$(?<=\.py)( |$)` as filter.**

So `(^|[\W])(?<file>(?:\p{Alpha}\:|/)[0-9 a-z_A-Z\-\\./]+)(?<=\.py)` is regexp used for `$FILE_PATH`. Source: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/d29c4fa1a73e03b852353186d792540150336b9f/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/execution/filters/RegexpFilter.java#L39
See how it allows spaces in there?

Meaning it will grab `C:\dev\path\to\a\project\file.py Imports are incorrectly sorted.` and as it does not point to a real file it won't be converted to a link.

So you can either modify *isort* output format to something with clear filepath boundaries, or use something more fancy in regexp like positive look behind, which would make your filter look like this:
`$FILE_PATH$(?<=\.py)( |$)`

For testing java regexps you can use https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html if the provided filter does not meet your particular needs.